# Got controller gains for six-axis manipulator?

Tags: pid, ros-kinetic, ur10, gazebo-ros, universal-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have working PID gains for the `effort_controllers/JointTrajectoryController` of a six-axis manipulator that I could use as a starting point for tuning the gains on a UR10?  The `universal_robot` package uses the `PositionJointInterface` class for getting the joints to their desired positions but this mechanism causes unrealistic interactions between the manipulator and the Gazebo environment.  For that reason I've changed the package locally to use the `EffortJointInterface` following [this example](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/commit/6c4318a3c0024be31e919cdd30741456f4eaf778#comments).  The author notes that the gains there are not working.  Please share with me any advice on tuning a 6-R 'bot or working gains for a manipulator.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303486/got-controller-gains-for-six-axis-manipulator?/) by [raequin](https://answers.ros.org/users/33937/raequin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 368 on 2018-09-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) on 2019-03-20**:
Do you have the values which worked for you?

**Comment by [raequin](https://answers.ros.org/users/33937/raequin/) on 2019-03-20**:
The values at the link in the accepted answer worked well.

```
linear_arm_actuator_joint: {p: 10000, d: 500, i: 0, i_clamp: 1}
shoulder_pan_joint: {p: 10000, d: 150, i: 0, i_clamp: 1}
shoulder_lift_joint: {p: 50000, d: 150, i: 10, i_clamp: 50}
elbow_joint: {p: 50000, d: 150, i: 1, i_clamp: 25}
wrist_1_joint: {p: 100, d: 5, i: 0, i_clamp: 1}
wrist_2_joint: {p: 75, d: 2, i: 0, i_clamp: 1}
wrist_3_joint: {p: 25, d: 1, i: 0, i_clamp: 1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know whether they "work", but you could take a look at the values that OSRF used for the ARIAC 2017 competition: [osrf/ariac/src/osrf_gear/launch/ur10/arm_controller_ur10_custom.yaml](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/ariac/src/de9f92a60aab743c6c7f8bf273cb732c34a51320/osrf_gear/launch/ur10/arm_controller_ur10_custom.yaml?at=ariac_2017&fileviewer=file-view-default#arm_controller_ur10_custom.yaml-21:28).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raequin](https://answers.ros.org/users/33937/raequin/) on 2018-09-17**:
Those values perform better for me than the original ones in the link included in the question.  The ones you referred to are a good starting point for tuning :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-17**:
If you manage to improve the behaviour by using different values, it would be nice if you could post here to let us know which values you used.

**Comment by [raequin](https://answers.ros.org/users/33937/raequin/) on 2018-09-24**:
The first time I used the posted gains was with a voluminous tool on the robot and the manipulator had a lot of overshoot.  Since then, my simulations have used more conventional tooling and performance has been fine.  That is, these gains seem okay to me :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-24**:
Nice.

We might add them as defaults to the improved version of the `universal_robot` packages.